# Disable firefox persona instant preview

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, personas

I find it highly annoying having the entire browser flicker and act up when moving the mouse over a persona. How can i disable the instant preview for firefox personas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that.

Install the Personas Plus extension from http://www.getpersonas.com/en-US. After you install and restart Firefox, go to addons (tools > addons), click preferences for the Personas Plus addon, and uncheck "show preview when selecting from menu".

Answer (score 1):

It is a piece of Javascript running that is annoying you so the easiest way to disable it is to install the [NoScript add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722/). Once installed you can easily set it up to block the page in question from running the javascript that is annoying you.